# SFTP ",u" (comma and u letter) option when downloading from HP-UX server

Tags: sftp, hp-ux

I was downloading a file from one HP-UX server, to an Red Hat Linux server. The file is around 6 or 7 GB.

Using `sftp`, I tried getting the file, but no matter how many times I try, it always reaches 80% and just exits. No error code, no error description, nothing.

Another team was copying the same file, so they shared their script, and apparently, in the `get` command, they add `",u"`:

```
get XYZ,u XYZ
```

I tried doing that and to my surprise it worked. However I cannot find that option anywhere else online, and I sort of want to know what is it.

Answer (score 0):

It must be some server-specific hack.

It's not an `sftp` option. From the local `sftp` client perspective, you are downloading a file with a name `XYZ,u`.